# How to access iframe element from main page and enable datapicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Main html:

this main page loads the summary html using iframe

```
<iframe id="ifAS" scrolling="no" src="Summary.html" seamless="seamless" name="ifAS"></iframe>
```

Summary html:

Summary html has input field which has to show datepicker option.

```
<form>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Summary_Date" id="Summary_Date" placeholder="DateOfAudit">
</form>
```

Javascript -

this javascript is used in html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    var frame = document.getElementById('ifAS');
    var inputt = frame.contentWindow.document.getElementsById('Summary_Date');
    inputt.datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    });
}
```

How to set datepicker for the summary_date element???